# Why doesn't my git auto-update Expect script work?

Tags: linux, git, bash, github, expect

I wanted to make a script that would update all of my GitHub repositories.

I would just need to enter my Username and my Password, and the script would go through a list of repositories, call `git push` and provide the necessary information via a supplementary Expect script.

This is my bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Updating GitHub projects from project_list.txt."
echo

read -p "GitHub username: " un
read -p "GitHub password: " -s pw

echo
echo

while read line
do
    eval dir=$line
    echo "Updating:" $dir"."
    cd $dir
    $SF/githubexpect $un $pw
    echo
    echo
done < $SF/project_list.txt
```

`$SF` is a global environment variable that contains an absolute path to my script folder.

Here is the githubexpect script:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect

set un [lindex $argv 0]
set pw [lindex $argv 1]

spawn git push

expect "Username"
send $un\n

expect "Password"
send $pw\n
```

When I run the bash script, things go as expected.

1. I am prompted for the info.
2. The script successfully starts and continues reading the `project_list.txt` file.
3. Once it finds itself in the repository's directory, it calls the githubexpect script and *correctly* passes on the info (I've tested this).
4. githubexpect correctly spawns `git push`.
5. It gets prompted for the input (I saw this in the console).
6. It does provide my info (again, I saw this too).
7. Then it just continues on to the next repository like nothing happened. **<-- Error!**

I am suspecting that the githubexpect script might be spawning `git push` relative to itself, and not the directory the current script is being executed in, so git doesn't even find a repository. This is probably false though as my script folder, in which githubexpect resides, is a repository as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be sending `\r` instead of `\n`. However the real problem is you don't wait for `git push` to complete. Add this as the last line of the expect script

```
expect eof
```

Comment: It works now! Would you mind explaining why do programs return `eof` when they are done? Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessarily that the program returns eof: the spawned program exits, and Expect happens to use the keyword "eof" for that condition.