# Auto answer bash script prompts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, github, sh

I'm trying to run "[git pull-request](https://hub.github.com/#work) ..." from a bash script.
When executed, it prompts for username & password.
How can I auto answer that from the script itself?

Thanks.

UPDATE:
Eventually I used expect as suggested by @eric-renouf.
That solved the issue for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can just set configuration info to prevent the prompting, but if not this could well be a job for `expect`

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to do that with "expect"?

Comment: Apparently, there's an [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request) so you could use `curl` or a tool called `hub` (see [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302570/automatically-open-a-pull-request-on-github-by-command-line))   For an example using `expect` with `git` see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092636/why-doesnt-my-git-auto-update-expect-script-work)

Comment: lot of expect examples http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/10/expect-examples

Comment: Add an SSH key to the account, and it won't prompt you for a password at all.

Comment: [hub](https://hub.github.com/) always uses https so the SSH key is not the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

have yo you tried

```
git config credential.helper store
```

or adding user name/password to your URL ?

```
https://user:pass@domain/repo
```

Comment: Yes. Not Working.